# python boundingRect with list of points

Tags: python, opencv

I got an error when trying to use the `boundingRect()` function in opencv. What given is a list of points

```
lists = []
for match in enumerate(matches):
    lists.append(kp2[match.trainIdx].pt)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(lists)
```

> TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

P/s: I want to draw a rectangle around the detected object in the image

Any help is appreciate

**Edit**

The lists before change to np array

`[(328.0, 227.0), (372.0, 241.0), (366.0, 229.0)]`

and after

`[[ 328.  227.]
 [ 372.  241.]
 [ 366.  229.]]`

Comment: Use a numpy array or a scalar. All you have to do is look at the error message

Comment: `error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function cv::pointSetBoundingRect` got this error from opencv, it seems that the function only read 1 object in the array.

Answer (score 3):

I just had exactly the same issue. Didn't resolve it but here is the code that solved the problem:

```
points = ([1,1], [3,1], [3,3], [1,4])

xx, yy = zip(*points)
min_x = min(xx); min_y = min(yy); max_x = max(xx); max_y = max(yy)
bbox = [(min_x, min_y), (max_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (min_x, max_y)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The list of points needs to be passed as a numpy array.
Therefore, first convert it, e.g. with

```
lists = np.array(lists, dtype=np.float32)
```

The failed assertion

```
'error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function cv::pointSetBoundingRect'
```

is triggered if the created numpy array does not have the datatype `float32` or `int32`. Another reason would be if the passed array does not contain any points.

The parameter `dtype=np.float32` in the array creation command ensures that the created array has the datatype `float32`. In a 64bit environment, omitting this parameter will lead to the array being created with datatype `float64`, which causes the assertion to fail.

After the conversion to a numpy array with datatype `float32`, passing the result to `cv.boundingRectangle` will work as expected.

*Intentionally answering an old question after I was directed here by a search engine.*